# ASP.net REST service with MS SQL base serializing list as null

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml, serialization

Running a ASP.net REST service using a MS SQL server as base.

Model

```
public class Bookings
{
    [Key]
    public int BookingId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public List<string> BookISBN { get; set; }

}
```

Sample generated documentation showing the format as "correct"
[image]

Sending following data over postman

```
{
  "BookingId": 1,
  "UserID": 2,
  "BookISBN": [
    "sample string 1",
    "sample string 2",
    "sample string 3"
  ]
}
```

However the last list "BookISBN" column is not generated, and API returns parameter as NULL / i:nil="true"

[image]

```
<ArrayOfBookings xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PublisherDataModel">
<Bookings>
<BookISBN xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true"/>
<BookingId>1</BookingId>
<UserID>2</UserID>
</Bookings>
<Bookings>
<BookISBN xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true"/>
<BookingId>2</BookingId>
<UserID>2</UserID>
</Bookings>
</ArrayOfBookings>
```

POST controller for Bookings.

```
    // POST api/Bookings
    [ResponseType(typeof(Bookings))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostBooking(Bookings Booking)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Bookings.Add(Booking);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = Booking.BookingId }, Booking);
    }
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should decorate your action with `HttpPost`;

```
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(Bookings))]
public IHttpActionResult PostBooking(Bookings Booking)
```

Comment: Done, no impact as far as the problem goes tho.

Answer (score 0):

I had to include / reference it specifically

```
 db.Entry(Booking).Reference(b => b.BookISBNList).Load();
```